# How do I read in a Formula in Excel and convert it to do the computation in Python?

Tags: python, excel, formula

I have a table of time-series data downloaded from some system. Say it is the revenue data for different persons across time. Eg below

```
**Table 1**
|      | Jan 1999| Feb 1999|Dec 1999|
|----- | --------| --------|--------|
| Peter| 9000    | 2000    |1000    |
| John | 6000    | 1000    |5000    |
```

The data is read into Python via pandas and converted into a dataframe.

Next, I need to read in from an Excel file, the formula I need to use for computation for Table 1.

Eg in the Excel file, the listed formula for Table 1 is
"=sum(Jan 1999: Dec 1999)"

Is there a way for Python code to know how to interpret this formula and do the computation for each row in Table 1?

So the result for Table 1:
Peter=12,000;
John=12,000

Thank you

Comment: Apologies, I can't get the table to look like a table. Not sure how to insert a table in a post in Stack overflow

Comment: In future, to format a table like a table, use the code button `{ }`.

Comment: There is a way, but you have to get Excel to do it for you. On Windows you install Python Extensions for Windows (https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) and use the module `pythoncom` to get Excel to open the file and do the calculations for you.

Comment: `=sum(Jan 1999: Dec 1999)` is not an excel formula.. right? (`=sum(B2:D2)` is an excel formula)

Comment: @p._phidot_Hi, "=sum(Jan 1999: Dec 1999)" is based on the header of the Table 1 which is read into Python. I need to do the computation in Python, NOT Excel. "=sum(Jan 1999: Dec 1999)"  is input into Excel by a user to tell Python the formula to use

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the module [`formulas`](https://formulas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) would be appropriate for what you're trying to do, allowing to parse and compute Excel formulas without having to open Excel all over again.

I did not dig deep into understanding the library, so maybe someone who has used it can complement my answer with an actual code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I am aware of formulas but the explanation of the module is difficult to comprehend.